# selecting an anchor tag on jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using 2 anchor tags on header part the of page and I want to catch click events on them so I can open panels. If I use buttons instead of anchor tags I can catch them easily with their id's such as;

```
 $(document).on('click', function(evt){
        var target = evt.target;
        var targetId = target.getAttribute('id');

        if(targetId === 'openRightPanel'){
            $('.right-panel').panel('open');
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
}
```

but if I use anchor tags I can't get click events like this;

```
if(targetId === 'openRightPanel'){
            $('.right-panel').panel('open');
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
}
```

even though my anchor tag has id of openRightPanel.

I realized jQuery mobile is creating some new divs in my html so I started using this code to catch that click event;

```
    while (target !== null) {
                if(target['id'] === 'openLeftPanel'){
                    $('.left-panel').panel('open');
                    isPreventOn = true;
                }
                else if(target['id'] === 'openRightPanel'){
                    $('.right-panel').panel('open');
                    isPreventOn = true;
                }
                target = target.parentNode;
            }
```

this one is working fine but creating some problems on android 4.1 and having a while loop to just catch a click event didn't seem right to me.

So my question is how can I catch click events that are made to these anchor tags in **jQuery mobile** without having loop or is there a different way to get that event?  These are the anchor tags that I want to get;

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <a id="openLeftPanel">open</a>
    <a id="openRightPanel">open</a>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

Comment: Anchors in header get converted into buttons. You can attach listeners to both. Are those anchors created dynamically or are static? http://fiddle.jshell.net/PYHRJ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly have the click events on the selector

```
$("#openLeftPanel").off('click').on('click', function(evt){

});

$("#openRightPanel").off('click').on('click', function(evt){

});
```

Comment: Yes it did work, but why this is not working if I attach it to document. What is the difference I was using this way to have a better performance.

Comment: @BurakBayram attaching event document, means all items within document, which means slow performance due to listening and processing each and every click.

Answer (score 0):

Don't attach the click event to the document, attach it to the anchor elements.

You have:

```
$(document).on('click', function(evt){...});
```

You should have:

```
$('[data-role="header"] a').on('click',function(evt){...});
```

Or, just separate the function for both:

```
$('#openLeftPanel').on('click',function(evt){...});
$('#openRightPanel').on('click',function(evt){...});
```

Comment: Yes it did work, but why this is not working if I attach it to document. What is the difference I was using this way to have a better performance.